# Back slash (\) should not be printed with echo command

Tags: linux, bash, awk, echo, cut

I have a parameter file (param.env) having the following content.

```
MY_PARAM=com:27}WMV\)pviZN
```

also, a bash file where I am fetching the value of MY_PARAM and writing into a random file.

```
#!/bin/bash


value=$(grep "^MY_PARAM=" param.env | cut -d '=' -f2-)

value1=$(cat param.env | grep "^MY_PARAM" | sed 's/=/ /' | awk '{print $2}')
echo $value

echo $value1

printf '%s\n' "$value"
```

Output:

```
com:27}WMV\)pviZN
com:27}WMV\)pviZN
com:27}WMV\)pviZN
```

However, I am expecting `\` to be escaped and should not be part of the output.
I am also not allowed to edit the param.env.

Expected output:

```
com:27}WMV)pviZN
```

Comment: May I ask why you cannot use sed to remove backslash?

Comment: what happens when the next char after ` \\` is `n` or `t` instead of `)` in your string?

Comment: The result of the command substitution is not subject to quote removal; the backslash is part of the value, not escaping the `)`.

Comment: At least according to the readme at https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv, there is no provision (other than replacing `\n` with a real newline) for escaping single characters using a backslash in a `.env` file.

Comment: The only reason you would need the backslash is if the line were processed by a shell as an assignment, since the `)` would treated as a meta character. Maybe whoever wrote `param.env` assumed that it *would* be processed as a shell script; I'm not aware of any hard-and-fast rules for exactly how a `.env` file should be parsed.

Comment: Why does the backslash exist in your file in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

You could source the file, then the string will behave as if you'd assigned it like that in an interactive shell:

```
$ (. param.env; echo "$MY_PARAM")
com:27}WMV)pviZN
```

I've put the commands in a subshell so they don't pollute the environment.

Comment: ... and maybe export result back into var `value` of current shell?

Comment: @alecxs That's impossible (a child shell can't modify the parent shell), but you could do something like `param=$(. param.env; echo "$MY_PARAM")`